# Mature text reading software? (text to speech)

Tags: speech-synthesis

During car driving, I would like to listen to articles published online read aloud by some software.

Is there any software for that giving more or less acceptable quality?

To the harfware setup, ideally it should be an app, but if more resources required worth to have good performance, I would install a barebone PC in my car.

"Ideal" use case:

1. Enter car.
2. Open (control) app
3. Optionally, add article URLs on the reading list
4. Press "PLAY".. er,  "READ ALOUD"
5. Drive and enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

I developed [Intelligent Speaker](https://intelligent-speaker.com) - extension for browser. Best on the market text-to-speech engine from Amazon, works on any operating system.

[image: Intelligent Speaker text-to-speech browser extension]

Comment: Cool, thank you! Can it work offline? Does it support German?

Comment: Offline on the side of the extension is planned, but already now we sync your articles with your personal podcast feed - and yes usually podcast clients able to play episodes offline, for example podcast app that preinstalled into iOS, almost any third-party for Android. German is supported - the language of the article on page detected automatically.

Answer (score 2):

[TextAloud](https://nextup.com/TextAloud/index.html) allows you to convert text to audio. For example, you can convert a PDF book to an MP3, using your pc, and then listen to the audio file on your phone in your car. In one hour you could convert more text to audio than you'd be able to listen to in your car driving a whole month.